# I can not load Application CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Using Link http://localhost/CakePHP/CakePHP/cruds [**cruds** is my Controller name] gives me error **CakePHP controller not found.**

Below is my directory structure.

[image]

`htdocs > CakePHP > CakePHP` [inside this folder all CakePHP's directory exists i.e. src, vendor,plugins etc.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like your cakePHP src is in a directory higher

http://localhost/CakePHP/ or http://localhost/CakePHP/cruds

Comment: no its in the second folder.. first cakePHP folder contains NodeJS code. Uploading image require 10 reputation so i am bounded else i would show you my directory with image

Comment: help plz @Alex Stallen

Comment: If I would guess it is that your 2 directories with the same name are messing up your routing or mod rewrite, try renaming them to something that makes sence.